# Getting 'Uncaught type error' in a p5.js sketch that I can't figure out

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, p5.js

I'm working with a very simple example of a p5.js that was part of the supplemental material for *Learning Processing*. They provide .js versions of all of the examples from the book, and my data viz project will go on the web. What I want to do is use this simple example to act as a template for when I create my actual data viz. I want to get the basic animation working first before I add a bunch of other code.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
var message = "random characters flying home!";
// An array of Letter objects
var letters;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 200);
  // Load the font
  textFont("Georgia", 20);

  // Create the array the same size as the String
  letters = [];
  // Initialize Letters at the correct x location
  var x = 50;
  var y = height/2;
  for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    letters[i] = new Letter(x, y, message.charAt(i));
    x += textWidth(message.charAt(i));
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    // Display all letters randomly
    letters[i].random();
}
    // If the mouse is pressed the letters return to their original location
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
          letters[i].display();
    }
  }

function Letter(x, y, letter) {
  // The object knows its original " home " location
  // As well as its current location
  this.homex = this.x = x;
  this.homey = this.y = y;
  this.letter = letter;
  this.theta = 0;

  // Bring the letters back to their original position
  this.display = function() {
    fill(0);
    textAlign(LEFT);
    this.x = this.homex;
    this.y = this.homey;
    text(this.letter, this.x, this.y);
  }

  // Position the letters randomly
  this.random = function() {
    this.x += random(width);
    this.y += random(height);
    this.theta += random(-0.1, 0.1);
  }

   // no longer using this function, but it was part of the original 'if' statement
  // At any point, the current location can be set back to the home location     by calling the home() function.
  //this.home = function() {
    //this.x += lerp(this.x, this.homex, 0.05);
    //this.y += lerp(this.y, this.homey, 0.05);
    //this.theta += lerp(this.theta, 0, 0.05);
    //text(this.letter);
      }
};
```

**ISSUE 1:** What it's supposed to do is initially display individual letters on the canvas. And it does that. But I also get the following error in my console:

> sketch.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'home' of undefined

`sketch.js:31` is the line at the end of the 'if' statement under `draw()`. My question is what is `'home'` referring to and how can I fix it.

**ISSUE 2:** What's supposed to happen when `mouseIsPressed` is the letters move into their correct configuration, i.e., "random characters flying home!" But nothing happens when I press down on the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not produce the errors you mentioned.

Instead, running your code produces an `unexpected token: }` error because you have an extra `}` at the end of your code. Get rid of it.

At that point you have a different error: `sketch.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined`. Looking at your `draw()` function, which includes line 29, we see this:

```
function draw() {
  background(255);
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    // Display all letters randomly
    letters[i].random();
  }
  // If the mouse is pressed the letters return to their original location
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    letters[i].display();
  }
}
```

Notice that your `if(mousePressed)` statement is **after** the `for` loop. What do you expect the value of `i` to be when you get to the if statement? Since it's outside the loop, `i` is out of scope, so its value is undefined! That's why you're getting this error.

To fix it, you need to rearrange your if statements so that they happen inside the loop:

```
function draw() {
  background(255);

  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

    if (mouseIsPressed) {
      // If the mouse is pressed the letters return to their original location
      letters[i].display();
    } else {
      // Display all letters randomly
      letters[i].random();
    }
  }
}
```

This gets rid of your errors, but your random logic is still off. You're just adding random values to your letters, so they fly off the screen and you can't see them.

Instead, add smaller values to their positions, and make sure you reset their positions when the user clicks.